# Make an EditText View(zipcode) to be loaded automatically

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on an app in which when user click on a button then a new activity layout
will be opened.This new layout contains various views.

One of them is zip-code `EditText` .I want that this zip-code `EditText` automatically fetch the zip-code of user through `GPS` and fill it in.For this I want to work like this:

1. User click on a button.
2. A new layout loads.
3. All views load perfectly and in front of zip-code `EditText` a loading button will be shown
   and it shows automatically by GPS.

How do I work on 3rd point i.e, showing loading until user zip code not fetched.

Comment: Post the code where you handle the 3rd point.

Comment: The best way is show a progress bar until the request procession is finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following pieces of code as an example. You will have to fill in some blanks though.

This is how I show a `ProgressBar` in one of my app's `Activities`. It has a ListView, which you will have to replace with your own content.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp" >
        </ProgressBar>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="Loading...."
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>
```

Now, in your Java code where you map this layout to your `Activity`, cast the `LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress`. Please note that in the XML itself, the `android:visibility="gone"` attribute is set to `"gone"`.

If you use an AsyncTask to fetch the ZIP code, then while the process happens in the `doInBackground()`, show the `ProgressBar` by toggling the visibility of the `linlaHeaderProgress` in the `onPreExecute()`like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    // SHOW THE PROGRESS BAR (SPINNER) WHILE FETCHING POST DETAILS
    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And in the `onPostExecute()`, again toggle the visibility like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    // HIDE THE PROGRESS BAR (SPINNER) AFTER FETCHING THE POST DETAILS
    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

If you are not using an AsyncTask, but are instead doing the processing in a `Method`, use this at the start of the method: linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);. And use this at the end of the method once you have displayed the ZIP code in the EditText: linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

I declare the `LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress` globally so I can reuse it wherever required. Let me know if this helps, or if you have any further questions for me.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth I am trying it and let you know If I faced any problem

Comment: @user2163887: Sure. Take your time.